# What are these black wall objects in Half Life 2?

Tags: half-life-2

I'm replaying Half-Life 2 and I'm puzzled about these objects:

[image: strange wall object]

What are these? What is their function? They sometimes move and crash into walls. It seems they are some kind of containment measure from the Combine's part but I did not find any explanation so far.

Comment: I don't think there is an explanation for it. I think it is just a hazard created for the player. The Half Life Universe is not that deep.

Answer (score 10):

I would try to explain it myself, but in truth when I came across the walls I never really thought twice of them. I did however Google "Half Life 2 walls" with a successful result.

http://half-life.wikia.com/wiki/Combine_Smart_Barrier

This should explain what they are far better than anything I could come up with.

> The Combine Smart Barrier, also known as the Combine Mobile Wall, is a large mechanized wall that uses powerful drive systems in tandem with heavy metal blocks to slowly expand outward and destroy existing structures in the way.

Comment: It's usually better to explain or quote the link you're linking in your answer and give the link as support than only give the link as an answer. If the link ever goes 404 the answer wont be valid anymore.

Answer (score -4):

The walls destroy existing structures to gain raw materials for combine production.

Comment: Could you add a source for this?